# what's c# Transacted?

Tags: c#

I work on someone else's code and it uses "Transacted" during class member implementation, eg:

```
void Smth.Add(type var)
{
    this.Smth.Transacted.Add(var);
}
```

What's Transacted?

Comment: Looks like a custom type or a Property on a custom Object.

Comment: @LikeToCode your avatar looks like pac-man!

Comment: Pressing F12 while the cursor is within the word `Transacted` will bring you to its definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it could be property or field name.